# Как декодировать такого вида json?

Tags: ios, swift

Доброго времени суток
Имею json такого вида

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"message": "GN News",
"content": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 159,
            "categoryId": 2,
            "createdAt": "2019-02-19 15:00:17",
            "alias": "159",
            "name": "Hello world",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/assets/img/article.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 157,
            "categoryId": 2,
            "createdAt": "2019-02-19 14:53:20",
            "alias": "157",
            "name": "Привет мир",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/assets/img/article.png"
        },
        {
            "id": 155,
            "categoryId": 4,
            "createdAt": "2019-02-15 12:00:00",
            "alias": "155-vnimanie-vyigray-cuper-priz-ot-generation-next",
            "name": "Внимание! ВЫИГРАЙ Cупер приз от Generation Next!",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1550231921.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 122,
            "categoryId": 6,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-30 12:00:00",
            "alias": "122-13-obrazovatelnykh-kanalov-na-youtube-kotorye-uvlekut-shkolnika",
            "name": "13 образовательных каналов на Youtube, которые увлекут школьника",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 1,
            "avatar": "/images/1548847740.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 118,
            "categoryId": 3,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-29 12:00:00",
            "alias": "118-master-klass-po-akterskomu-masterstvu-dlya-detey-proydet-v-astane-2-fevralya-v-1430",
            "name": "МАСТЕР-КЛАСС ПО АКТЕРСКОМУ МАСТЕРСТВУ ДЛЯ ДЕТЕЙ ПРОЙДЕТ В АСТАНЕ 2 ФЕВРАЛЯ В 14:30",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548779011.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 119,
            "categoryId": 5,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-29 12:00:00",
            "alias": "119-kak-do-70-let-ostavatbsya-v-forme-i-proyti-ironman",
            "name": "КАК ДО 70 ЛЕТ ОСТАВАТЬСЯ В ФОРМЕ И ПРОЙТИ IRONMAN",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 0,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548779287.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "categoryId": 8,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-27 12:00:00",
            "alias": "103-talantty-azastandy-rezhisser-anat-beysekeevti-tuyndysy-kshpendiler",
            "name": "Талантты қазақстандық режиссер Қанат Бейсекеевтің туындысы: \"Көшпенділер\"",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 1,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548587159.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 104,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-27 12:00:00",
            "alias": "104-nazarbaev-priznan-samoy-znachimoy-lichnostyu-tyurkskogo-mira",
            "name": "Назарбаев признан самой значимой личностью тюркского мира",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 1,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548587573.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 106,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-27 12:00:00",
            "alias": "106-kakie-imena-zapreshcheny-v-raznykh-stranakh-mira-za-germionu-kak-to-obidno",
            "name": "Какие имена запрещены в разных странах мира (За Гермиону как-то обидно)",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 2,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548591548.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 108,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-27 12:00:00",
            "alias": "108-samye-vysokooplachivaemye-didzhei-mira",
            "name": "Самые высокооплачиваемые диджеи мира",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 2,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548593742.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 109,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-27 12:00:00",
            "alias": "109-nasilie-i-zapugivanie-v-shkole-novaya-globalnaya-problema",
            "name": "Насилие и запугивание в школе — новая глобальная проблема",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 1,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548594132.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 95,
            "categoryId": 1,
            "createdAt": "2019-01-24 12:00:00",
            "alias": "95-nazarbaevty-atysuymen-zhastar-zhyly-ashyldy",
            "name": "Назарбаевтың қатысуымен Жастар жылы ашылды",
            "checked": false,
            "favoritesCount": 2,
            "commentsCount": 0,
            "avatar": "/images/1548327795.JPEG"
        }
    ],
    "next": "2"
}}
```

Декодирую его так

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let statusCode: Int
    let message: String
    let content: Content
}

struct Content: Codable {
    let items: [Item]
    let next: String
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let id, categoryID: Int
    let createdAt, alias, name: String
    let checked: Bool
    let favoritesCount, commentsCount: Int
    let avatar: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case categoryID = "categoryId"
        case createdAt, alias, name, checked, favoritesCount, commentsCount, avatar
    }
}
```

Создаю переменную такого типа

```
var arrData = [Content]()
```

Затем создаю функцию и пишу туда следующее

```
let data_new = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
self.ArrData = data_new.content.items
```

И все после этого он не видит содержимое `items`
Как правильно декодировать данный json?

Comment: У Вас JSON не валиден:
https://jsonformatter.org/40456b

Comment: Поменял, скинул полный

Comment: @Marshall Возможно, Вы неправильно инициализируете `data`. Можете добавить больше кода в вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в этом

```
var arrData = [Item]()
```